# Do I need a transit visa in South Korea?

Tags: transit-visas, south-korea, filipino-citizens, korean-air, philippine-airlines

I'm a US green card holder, planning to take a vacation to the Philippines. Do I need a transit visa if I just have a connecting flight to South Korea going to the Philippines?

Comment: Filipino citizen

Answer (score 1):

According to [Visa requirements for Philippine citizens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_requirements_for_Philippine_citizens):

> - Green Card holders in the United States do not need a visa to visit or transit in South Korea.